# getItemViewType for differents Sections Items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, header, android-viewholder, items, getview

I use the library of [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter)
I have 3 Header and 3 SectionItems,
I need to implement a library for these sections items: [Slice](https://github.com/mthli/Slice)
To display the Radius corners on each SectionItems,

But the radius is attributed only to the first section, I do not know or is the problem. I am unable to get the rounded corners for other sections.

[image]

```
public  class SectionItem extends AbstractSectionableItem<SectionItem.DataCellViewHolder,HeaderItem> {

    public static String NAME = SectionItem.class.getName();

    public class DataCellViewHolder extends FlexibleViewHolder implements DataCellViewHolder2 {

        FrameLayout frame;
        TextView title;

        DataCellViewHolder(View itemView, FlexibleAdapter adapter) {
            super(itemView, adapter);
            frame = (FrameLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        }

        @Override
        public FrameLayout getFrame() {
            return frame;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
             mAdapter.getSectionItems(getHeader()).size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (position==1){
                return VIEW_TYPE_TOP;
            }  else if (position == getItemCount()) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_BOTTOM;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_CENTER;
            }
        }
    }

    private String title;

    public SectionItem(String title, HeaderItem header) {
            super(header);
            this.title = title;
            setDraggable(true);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public HeaderItem getHeader() {
        return super.getHeader();
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindViewHolder( FlexibleAdapter adapter, DataCellViewHolder holder, int position, List payloads) {
        holder.title.setText(title);

        Slice slice = new Slice(holder.getFrame());
        slice.setElevation(2.0f);

        int view = holder.getItemViewType(position);

            if (view == VIEW_TYPE_TOP) {
                slice.setRadius(8.0f);
                slice.showLeftTopRect(false);
                slice.showRightTopRect(false);
                slice.showRightBottomRect(true);
                slice.showLeftBottomRect(true);
                slice.showTopEdgeShadow(true);
                slice.showBottomEdgeShadow(false);

            } else if (view == VIEW_TYPE_BOTTOM) {
                slice.setRadius(8.0f);
                slice.showLeftTopRect(true);
                slice.showRightTopRect(true);
                slice.showRightBottomRect(false);
                slice.showLeftBottomRect(false);
                slice.showTopEdgeShadow(false);
                slice.showBottomEdgeShadow(true);

            } else {
                slice.setRadius(0.0f);
                slice.showTopEdgeShadow(false);
                slice.showBottomEdgeShadow(false);
            }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object inObject) {
        if (inObject instanceof SectionItem) {
            SectionItem inItem = (SectionItem) inObject;
            return this.title.equals(inItem.title);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.item_center;
    }

    @Override
    public DataCellViewHolder createViewHolder(View view, FlexibleAdapter adapter) {
        Log.w(NAME, " : createViewHolder");
        return new DataCellViewHolder(view, adapter);
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3be13e"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ahmed.flexibleadapterdemo.MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</FrameLayout>
```

item_center.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/plus_sign">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the code of the xmls used for the items?

Comment: The post is edited with XML files

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how FlexibleAdapter work,so i suggest use a attr: background with your view "R.id.frame" to make the radius;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/color_bg"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I try this method but unfortunately it returns the background for all the items and I want one for each section

Comment: @RabahBoulhares opps,can not help you.